# Interrupting an Animation

Tags: animation, windows-phone

Picture a Windows Phone.

There is a ball (a circle).

When you tap somewhere the ball moves toward that tap.

When it reaches that spot, it stops.

You tap somewhere else.

The ball moves toward that second spot.

BUT, before it reaches its destination, you tap somewhere else. A third tap.

Now the ball changes directions toward the third tap.

To move toward a tap - this is a simple animation.

To change course mid-stream; **how do you do that?**

If I simply stop the first animation, there is no easing.

I need to change courses gently, smoothly.

An ideas?

Comment: SILVERLIGHT, sorry for not stating.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the easing to stop right where the ball is at point 2 and then the easing to start moving to point 3, I would do something like this:

1. Modify endpoint (second spot) to be 10-20 pixels from the balls current location in the direction of second spot.
2. When the spot reaches the new second spot, start moving toward spot three.

Here is a diagram to help:

[image]

Comment: This is an excellent restatement of the question, thank you. Still looking for an answer. Your suggestion would create an angle, rather than a smooth change in direction.